# Transfer / Delete AVCHD contents over WIFI Handycam

Tags: sdk, sony

Anybody know a Sony Handycam model that support transfert content (AVCHD) over WIFI by the API ?
I have try with CX-625 but, the function seem to not be implemented.

thanks 
Alex

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need a camera that supports the Sony Camera Remote API. Unfortunately the HandyCam is not supported by the API, but you can see a full list of supported cameras here :

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Maybe you can use one of these as the Camera Remote API will allow you to take and transfer pictures and videos all over Wifi.